# Java Generics Lambda Compilation Error

Tags: java, generics, lambda, option-type, completable-future

i'm trying to implement a non-blocking DAO layer for my application developing in play framework(2.5.4). It gives me error in deleteById()

> no instance(s) of variable(s) U exists so that void conforms to U

```
abstract class BaseDao<E extends BaseModel> {
    JPAApi jpaApi;
    private Class<E> entityClazz;

    BaseDao(JPAApi jpaApi, Class<E> entityClazz) {
        this.jpaApi = jpaApi;
        this.entityClazz = entityClazz;
    }

    public CompletionStage<E> save(E entity) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            jpaApi.em().persist(entity);
            return entity;
        });
    }

    public CompletionStage<Optional<E>> findById(String id) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Optional.ofNullable(jpaApi.em().find(entityClazz, id))
        );
    }


    public void deleteById(String id) {
        findById(id).thenApply(
                result -> result.ifPresent(
                        //HERE IS WHERE MY IDE COMPLAINTS 
                        entity -> { 
                            entity.setActive(false);
                            save(entity);
                        }

                )
        );
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to understand why there's an error

- `Optional.ifPresent()` takes a Consumer, which returns `void`
- `CompletionStage.thenApply()` takes a `Function<T, U>`. The return type `U` must match the return type of the body of the lambda - in this case `Optional.ifPresent()`.
- `void` is a primitive type and doesn't have a boxed equivalent so the compiler is stumped.

One thing which you could do would be to convert the expression lambda to a block lambda that returns some kind of a value.
e.g.

```
    findById(id).thenApply(
            result -> { 
                       result.ifPresent(
                            entity -> { 
                                entity.setActive(false);
                                save(entity);
                            }
                        );
                        return 1;
                    }
    );
```

That should allow the compiler to tie together the types - `thenApply()` will be taking a `Function` returning an `Integer`, while `ifPresent()` is still able to take a `Consumer` returning void.

Alternatively, and probably preferably, you could use the `thenAccept()` method on `CompletionStage()`, which accepts a `Consumer` rather than a `Function`...

```
    findById(id).thenAccept(
            result -> result.ifPresent(
                    entity -> { 
                        entity.setActive(false);
                        save(entity);
                    }
            )
    );
```